# Creating a VBA loop to validate results of two nested functions across a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have been racking my brain trying to figure out how to nest a function inside a for each loop in order to run the same validation against each result and add it to a list if it meets the criteria.

So the base function I am using grabs 2 lat/long sets and gets distance in KM between the two. Listed below:

```
Public Function getDistance(latitude1,longitude1,latitude2,longitude2)
earth_radius = 6371
Pi = 3.14159265
deg2rad = Pi / 180

dLat = deg2rad * (latitude2 - latitude1)
dLon = deg2rad * (longitude2 - longitude1)

a = Sin(dLat / 2) * Sin(dLat / 2) + Cos(deg2rad * latitude1) * Cos(deg2rad * latitude2) * Sin(dLon / 2) * Sin(dLon / 2)
c = 2 * WorksheetFunction.Asin(Sqr(a))

d = earth_radius * c

getDistance = d

End Function
```

So what I want to do with this is run it against a two lists of locations and do a for loop where, in pseudocode, it would be: **For each location in list A; create a list of each location within 5km (getDistance result)**.

I have a second block of code from extendoffice that seems to be close as it is a multi parameter vlookup listed below:

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
'Update 20150310
Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String
xResult = ""
For Each rng In pWorkRng

    If rng = pValue Then
        xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
    End If
Next
MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function
```

I cant seem for the life of me nest that function inside the vlookup to loop I know I have to call in the get distance function inside the for each loop but I think it might need to be a nested loop inside of that for loop.

Am I completely off here with my thinking? I am rather new to VBA, so what I am really having trouble is figuring out the syntax on this double nested loop...

**Update:**

So I thing I have gotten a bit further with what I need. I dont think I am going to try to compare the two ranges, rather just bring in the latitude and longitude of the lookup variable into the function. So this is where I  got picture of what I am trying to achieve:

[spreadsheet snip with columns and results i am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDHAc.png)

The actual code of the two functions, the geographical distance query listed before and the function I tried to create:

```
Public Function getDistance(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2)
earth_radius = 6371
Pi = 3.14159265
deg2rad = Pi / 180

dLat = deg2rad * (latitude2 - latitude1)
dLon = deg2rad * (longitude2 - longitude1)

a = Sin(dLat / 2) * Sin(dLat / 2) + Cos(deg2rad * latitude1) * Cos(deg2rad * latitude2) * Sin(dLon / 2) * Sin(dLon / 2)
c = 2 * WorksheetFunction.Asin(Sqr(a))

d = earth_radius * c

getDistance = d

End Function

Function findCloseStores(basesitelat As Double, basesitelong As Double, storeRange As Range)
    Dim xResult As String
    xResult = ""
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim worker As Double
    For Each rw In storeRange.Rows
        worker = getDistance(basesitelat, storeRange.Cells(rw.Row, 2), basesitelong, storeRange.Cells(rw.Row, 3))
        If worker <= 9.77 Then
            xResult = xResult & "," & storeRange.Cells(rw.Row, 1)
        End If
    Next rw
    findCloseStores = xResult
End Function
```

What I actually get as results is just blank. It is processing the function I gave it, but It isnt reading something right/i wrote something wrong in the findCloseStores function that is making it assume no parameters are met.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong on the findCloseStores function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that it's a nested loop. In outline, it can go like this: for each A, for each B, if the getDistance from A to B is short, then add B to a list, next B, save the list, next A.

Comment: I built a function against that, but I cant seem to get it to work. its processing without failure, but it sends no results. Any Idea as to what is wrong in my syntax?(edited the first question above with everything under "Update"

Comment: Put this line in your code: `worker = getDistance(basesitelat, basesitelong, rw.Cells(2), rw.Cells(3))`

The parameters were out of order. Also, the .Row property wasn't going to work, because it returns the row number on the worksheet.

After you edit the function, click Save. On the worksheet, double-click the cell with the function and press Enter.

Comment: Also change `storeRange.Cells(rw.Row, 1)` to `rw.Cells(1)`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! It makes sense that i didnt have to recall the range. What I ended up doing for the final script loop: `For Each rw In storeRange.Rows
        worker = getDistance(basesitelat, basesitelong, rw.Cells(2), rw.Cells(3))
        If worker <= 9.77 Then
            If xResult = "" Then
                xResult = rw.Cells(1)
            Else
                xResult = xResult & "," & rw.Cells(1)
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
    findCloseStores = xResult
End Function` I needed to nest another if to take away the first comma from showing as well

Comment: Nice nested If to include a comma between results. While you're using the Cells property, notice that it works with either one or two parameters. _Range_.Cells(_r, c_) specifies a cell by row and column of the range. _Range_.Cells(_n_) specifies a cell as the _nth_ item, such as the first cell or the 99th cell in the range.